# OpenGL fragment shader crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm using OpenGL 3.3 on Mac OSX 11.5.2. I have 6 fragment shaders, 3 that works and 3 that crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. They all use the same vertex shader. There have been many questions about this problem, but I've made sure to:

1. [Unbind my previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150441/opengl-es-exc-bad-access-on-gldrawarrays).
2. [Made sure attribute arrays enabled and used](https://community.khronos.org/t/shader-gldrawarrays-crash-only-on-nvidia-win32/69160/2)[.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867409/opengl-3-3-gldrawarrays-crashes)
3. [Am only using a single-thread, i.e. no concurrency.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251063/exc-bad-access-crash-gldrawarrays-while-opening-wepopover)

The shaders that crash are all using one array of offsets and a kernel to do post-processing effects. If I replace `texture_coordinate.st + offsets[i]` with just `texture_coordinate.st`, it'll work just fine. As this makes the `offsets` array unused and optimized out, I have a suspicion that it could be due to a register allocation bug as mentioned in the comments [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718998/exc-bad-access-when-calling-gldrawarrays), but can't confirm.

I've also checked for other problems, such as loading them in different orders, using different compiler flags, but the crashes are consistent.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example (dependent on glad and glfw3, compiled with c++17) with one of the problematic shaders.

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


const char VERTEX_POST[] = R"(
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_texture_coordinate;

out vec2 texture_coordinate;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    texture_coordinate = in_texture_coordinate;
}
)";

const char FRAGMENT_POST[] = R"(
#version 330 core

in vec2 texture_coordinate;

out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D image;

const float offset = 1.0 / 300.0;

void main()
{
    vec2 offsets[9] = vec2[](
        vec2(-offset,  offset),  // top-left
        vec2( 0.0f,    offset),  // top-center
        vec2( offset,  offset),  // top-right
        vec2(-offset,  0.0f),    // center-left
        vec2( 0.0f,    0.0f),    // center-center
        vec2( offset,  0.0f),    // center-right
        vec2(-offset, -offset),  // bottom-left
        vec2( 0.0f,   -offset),  // bottom-center
        vec2( offset, -offset)   // bottom-right
    );

    float kernel[9] = float[](
        -1, -1, -1,
        -1,  9, -1,
        -1, -1, -1
    );

    vec3 sample_texture[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        sample_texture[i] = vec3(texture(image, texture_coordinate + offsets[i]));

    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        color += sample_texture[i] * kernel[i];

    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
)";


float vertices[] = {
        // Positions         // Texture coords
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,     0.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,     1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,     0.0f,  1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,     0.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,     1.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,     1.0f,  1.0f
};

GLuint create_shader(const char* source, GLenum type)
{
    GLuint id = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &source, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int success;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    assert(success);

    return id;
}


int main()
{
    // ---- INIT GLFW & GLAD ----
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,        GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT,  GLFW_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "Temp", nullptr, nullptr);

    if (window == nullptr) return -1;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) return -1;


    // ---- CREATE QUAD ----
    GLuint quad, vbo;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glBindVertexArray(quad);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    // ---- CREATE TEXTURE ----
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    char data[800 * 800 * 4] = {};
    for (char& i : data) i = 127;
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 800, 800, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // ---- CREATE SHADER PROGRAM ----
    GLuint vertex_shader   = create_shader(VERTEX_POST,   GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragment_shader = create_shader(FRAGMENT_POST, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    int success;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    assert(success);


    // ---- MAIN LOOP ----
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(program);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "image"), 0);
        glBindVertexArray(quad);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The example gives me a grey image when not including `offsets` and otherwise exhibits the crash. What could be causing this?